# New Google sheet combining columns from multiple sheets with join based on common field

Tags: google-sheets

I've 3 or more Google sheets. Each sheet covers different aspects of employee info. These sheets would get new entries added every now and then. All the sheets have ID column.

The new sheet has UNION of all fields from different sheets joined by a common field present in every sheet, e.g. email id.

For example:
Source 1:
[image: User Response sheet]

Source 2:
[image: User Info sheet]

Expected new sheet with the integrated data joined by email id is:
[image]

Ideally, the integrated sheet should not have the repetition of join key, i.e. Email.

I want this integrated sheet to be automatically updated with new rows as and when new data comes in all the sheets. Ideally, this should happen when data in all the source sheets are complete for a given ID.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Sheets doesn't have `Document` as this is a term reserved for Google... `DOCUMENTS`.P Perhaps reword to avoid this term?

Answer (score 2):

use arrays `{}` like:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY({Sheet1!A2:B; Sheet2!A2:B; Sheet3!A2:B}; 
 "where Col1 is not null"))
```

---

### update 1:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY({
 IMPORTRANGE("url_of_spreadsheet_here"; "Sheet1!A2:B"); 
 IMPORTRANGE("url_of_spreadsheet_here"; "Sheet2!A2:B"); 
 IMPORTRANGE("url_of_spreadsheet_here"; "Sheet3!A2:B")}; 
 "where Col1 is not null"))
```

side note: each importrange formula needs to be run as standalone to connect your sheets by allowing access - only then you can use above formula

---

### update 2:

if columns are mixed you can "correct" them like:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY({
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url_of_spreadsheet_here"; "Sheet1!A2:C"); "select Col1,Col2,Col3"); 
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url_of_spreadsheet_here"; "Sheet2!A2:C"); "select Col3,Col2,Col1"); 
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url_of_spreadsheet_here"; "Sheet3!A2:C"); "select Col2,Col3,Col1")}; 
 "where Col1 is not null"))
```

Comment: The source sheets are independent files/links, not sheets within one single file.

Comment: Updated with illustration now. Different source sheets may have column names in any order. I don't see join criteria (in my case email id) in your query function. Could you please check?

Comment: Would the solution be on the line of VLOOKUP + IMPORTRANGE ?